# Xorshift1024* jump not commutative?

Tags: c++, random

I've been porting Sebastiano Vigna's [**xorshift1024***](http://xorshift.di.unimi.it/xorshift1024star.c) PRNG to be compatible with the standard C++11 uniform random number generator contract and noticed some strange behavior with the `jump()` function he provides.

According to Vigna, a call to `jump()` should be equivalent to 2^512 calls to `next()`.  Therefore a series of calls to `jump()` and `next()` should be commutative.  For example, assuming the generator starts in some known state,

```
jump();
next();
```

should leave the generator in the same state as

```
next();
jump();
```

since both should be equivalent to

```
for (bigint i = 0; i < (bigint(1) << 512) + 1; ++i)
    next();
```

assuming `bigint` is some integer type with an extremely large maximum value (and assuming you are a very, very, very patient person).

Unfortunately, this doesn't work with the reference implementation Vigna provides (which I will include at the end for posterity; in case the implementation linked above changes or is taken down in the future).  When testing the first two options using the following test code:

```
memset(s, 0xFF, sizeof(s));
p = 0;

// jump() and/or next() calls...

std::cout << p << ';';
for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    std::cout << ' ' << s[i];
```

calling `jump()` before `next()` outputs:

```
1; 9726214034378009495 13187905351877324975 10033047168458208082 990371716258730972 965585206446988056 74622805968655940 11468976784638207029 3005795712504439672 6792676950637600526 9275830639065898170 6762742930827334073 16862800599087838815 13481924545051381634 16436948992084179560 6906520316916502096 12790717607058950780
```

while calling `next()` first results in:

```
1; 13187905351877324975 10033047168458208082 990371716258730972 965585206446988056 74622805968655940 11468976784638207029 3005795712504439672 6792676950637600526 9275830639065898170 6762742930827334073 16862800599087838815 13481924545051381634 16436948992084179560 6906520316916502096 12790717607058950780 9726214034378009495
```

Clearly either my understanding of what `jump()` is doing is wrong, or there's a bug in the `jump()` function, or the jump polynomial data is wrong.  Vigna claims that such a jump function can be calculated for any stride of the period, but doesn't elaborate on how to calculate it (including in his [paper on xorshift* generators](http://vigna.di.unimi.it/ftp/papers/xorshift.pdf)).  How can I calculate the correct jump data to verify that there's not a typo somewhere in it?

---

Xorshift1024* reference implementation; http://xorshift.di.unimi.it/xorshift1024star.c

```
/*  Written in 2014-2015 by Sebastiano Vigna (vigna@acm.org)

To the extent possible under law, the author has dedicated all copyright
and related and neighboring rights to this software to the public domain
worldwide. This software is distributed without any warranty.

See <http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/>. */

#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

/* This is a fast, top-quality generator. If 1024 bits of state are too
   much, try a xorshift128+ generator.

   The state must be seeded so that it is not everywhere zero. If you have
   a 64-bit seed, we suggest to seed a splitmix64 generator and use its
   output to fill s. */

uint64_t s[16]; 
int p;

uint64_t next(void) {
    const uint64_t s0 = s[p];
    uint64_t s1 = s[p = (p + 1) & 15];
    s1 ^= s1 << 31; // a
    s[p] = s1 ^ s0 ^ (s1 >> 11) ^ (s0 >> 30); // b,c
    return s[p] * UINT64_C(1181783497276652981);
}


/* This is the jump function for the generator. It is equivalent
   to 2^512 calls to next(); it can be used to generate 2^512
   non-overlapping subsequences for parallel computations. */

void jump() {
    static const uint64_t JUMP[] = { 0x84242f96eca9c41dULL,
        0xa3c65b8776f96855ULL, 0x5b34a39f070b5837ULL, 0x4489affce4f31a1eULL,
        0x2ffeeb0a48316f40ULL, 0xdc2d9891fe68c022ULL, 0x3659132bb12fea70ULL,
        0xaac17d8efa43cab8ULL, 0xc4cb815590989b13ULL, 0x5ee975283d71c93bULL,
        0x691548c86c1bd540ULL, 0x7910c41d10a1e6a5ULL, 0x0b5fc64563b3e2a8ULL,
        0x047f7684e9fc949dULL, 0xb99181f2d8f685caULL, 0x284600e3f30e38c3ULL
    };

    uint64_t t[16] = { 0 };
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof JUMP / sizeof *JUMP; i++)
        for(int b = 0; b < 64; b++) {
            if (JUMP[i] & 1ULL << b)
                for(int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
                    t[j] ^= s[(j + p) & 15];
            next();
        }

    memcpy(s, t, sizeof t);
}
```

Comment: @deviantfan A typo :)  edited.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, I'm sorry but sometimes this happens (I'm the author).

Originally the function had two memcpy(). Then I realised then a circular copy was needed. But I replaced just the *first* memcpy(). Stupid, stupid, stupid. All files on the site have been fixed. The arXiv copy is undergoing update. See http://xorshift.di.unimi.it/xorshift1024star.c

Incidentally: I didn't "publish" anything wrong in the scientific sense, as the jump() function is not part of the ACM Trans. Math. Soft. paper—it just has been added few weeks ago on the site and on the arXiv/WWW version. The fast publication path of the web and arXiv means that, sometimes, one distributes unpolished papers. I can only thank the reporter for reporting this bug (OK, technically StackOverflow is not reporting bugs, but I got an email, too).

Unfortunately, the unit test I had did not consider the case p ≠ 0. My main concern was that the correctness of the computed polynomial. The function, as noted above, is correct when p = 0.

As for the computation: to each generator corresponds a characteristic polynomial P(x). The jump polynomial for k is just x^k mod P(x). I use fermat to compute such powers, and then I have some scripts generating the C code.

Of course I can't test 2^512, but since my generation code works perfectly from 2 to 2^30 (the range you can easily test), I'm confident it works at 2^512, too. It's just fermat computing x^{2^512} instead of x^{2^30}. But independent verifications are more than welcome.

I have code working only for powers of the form x^{2^t}. This is what I need to compute useful jump functions. Computing polynomials modulo P(x) is not difficult, so one could conceivably have a completely generic jump function for any value, but frankly I find this totally overkill.

If anybody is interested in getting other jump polynomials, I can provide the scripts. They will be part, as it happens for all other code, of the next xorshift distribution, but I need to complete the documentation before giving them out.

For the record, the characteristic polynomial of xorshift1024* is x^1024 + x^974 + x^973 + x^972 + x^971 + x^966 + x^965 + x^964 + x^963 + x^960 + x^958 + x^957 + x^956 + x^955 + x^950 + x^949 + x^948 + x^947 + x^942 + x^941 + x^940 + x^939 + x^934 + x^933 + x^932 + x^931 + x^926 + x^925 + x^923 + x^922 + x^920 + x^917 + x^916 + x^915 + x^908 + x^906 + x^904 + x^902 + x^890 + x^886 + x^873 + x^870 + x^857 + x^856 + x^846 + x^845 + x^844 + x^843 + x^841 + x^840 + x^837 + x^835 + x^830 + x^828 + x^825 + x^824 + x^820 + x^816 + x^814 + x^813 + x^811 + x^810 + x^803 + x^798 + x^797 + x^790 + x^788 + x^787 + x^786 + x^783 + x^774 + x^772 + x^771 + x^770 + x^769 + x^768 + x^767 + x^765 + x^760 + x^758 + x^753 + x^749 + x^747 + x^746 + x^743 + x^741 + x^740 + x^738 + x^737 + x^736 + x^735 + x^728 + x^726 + x^723 + x^722 + x^721 + x^720 + x^718 + x^716 + x^715 + x^714 + x^710 + x^709 + x^707 + x^694 + x^687 + x^686 + x^685 + x^684 + x^679 + x^678 + x^677 + x^674 + x^670 + x^669 + x^667 + x^666 + x^665 + x^663 + x^658 + x^655 + x^651 + x^639 + x^638 + x^635 + x^634 + x^632 + x^630 + x^623 + x^621 + x^618 + x^617 + x^616 + x^615 + x^614 + x^613 + x^609 + x^606 + x^604 + x^601 + x^600 + x^598 + x^597 + x^596 + x^594 + x^593 + x^592 + x^590 + x^589 + x^588 + x^584 + x^583 + x^582 + x^581 + x^579 + x^577 + x^575 + x^573 + x^572 + x^571 + x^569 + x^567 + x^565 + x^564 + x^563 + x^561 + x^559 + x^557 + x^556 + x^553 + x^552 + x^550 + x^544 + x^543 + x^542 + x^541 + x^537 + x^534 + x^532 + x^530 + x^528 + x^526 + x^523 + x^521 + x^520 + x^518 + x^516 + x^515 + x^512 + x^511 + x^510 + x^508 + x^507 + x^506 + x^505 + x^504 + x^502 + x^501 + x^499 + x^497 + x^494 + x^493 + x^492 + x^491 + x^490 + x^487 + x^485 + x^483 + x^482 + x^480 + x^479 + x^477 + x^476 + x^475 + x^473 + x^469 + x^468 + x^465 + x^463 + x^461 + x^460 + x^459 + x^458 + x^455 + x^453 + x^451 + x^448 + x^447 + x^446 + x^445 + x^443 + x^438 + x^437 + x^431 + x^430 + x^429 + x^428 + x^423 + x^417 + x^416 + x^415 + x^414 + x^412 + x^410 + x^409 + x^408 + x^400 + x^398 + x^396 + x^395 + x^391 + x^390 + x^386 + x^385 + x^381 + x^380 + x^378 + x^375 + x^373 + x^372 + x^369 + x^368 + x^365 + x^360 + x^358 + x^357 + x^354 + x^350 + x^348 + x^346 + x^345 + x^344 + x^343 + x^342 + x^340 + x^338 + x^337 + x^336 + x^335 + x^333 + x^332 + x^325 + x^323 + x^318 + x^315 + x^313 + x^309 + x^308 + x^305 + x^303 + x^302 + x^300 + x^294 + x^290 + x^281 + x^279 + x^276 + x^275 + x^273 + x^272 + x^267 + x^263 + x^262 + x^261 + x^260 + x^258 + x^257 + x^256 + x^249 + x^248 + x^243 + x^242 + x^240 + x^238 + x^236 + x^233 + x^232 + x^230 + x^228 + x^225 + x^216 + x^214 + x^212 + x^210 + x^208 + x^206 + x^205 + x^200 + x^197 + x^196 + x^184 + x^180 + x^176 + x^175 + x^174 + x^173 + x^168 + x^167 + x^166 + x^157 + x^155 + x^153 + x^152 + x^151 + x^150 + x^144 + x^143 + x^136 + x^135 + x^125 + x^121 + x^111 + x^109 + x^107 + x^105 + x^92 + x^90 + x^79 + x^78 + x^77 + x^76 + x^60 + 1

Answer (score 4):

tldr: I'm pretty sure there's a bug in the original code:
The `memcpy` in `jump()` must consider the `p` rotation too.
The author didn't test nearly as much as appropriate before publishing a paper...

Long version:

One `next()` call changes only one of the 16 `s` array elements, the one with index `p`. `p` starts at 0, gets increased each `next()` call, and after 15 it becomes 0 again. Let's call `s[p]` the "current" array element. Another (slower) possibility for implementing `next()` would be that the current element is always the first one, there is no `p`, and instead of incrementing `p` the whole `s` array is rotated (ie. the first element moves to the last position and the previous second element becomes the first).

Independent of the current `p` value, 16 calls to `next()` should result in the same `p` value as before, ie. the whole cycle is done and the current element is the same position as before the 16 calls. `jump()` should do 2^512 `next()`, 2^512 is a multiple of 16, so with one jump, the `p` value before and after it should be the same.

You probably noticed already that your two different results are only rotated one time, ie. one solution is "9726214034378009495 somethingelse" and one is "somethingelse 9726214034378009495"

...because you did *one* `next()` before/after the `jump()` and `jump()` *can't handle `p` other than 0*.

If you'd test it with 16 `next()` (or 32 or 0 or ...) before/after `jump()` instead of one, the two results are equal. The reason is, within jump, while for the `s` array the current element / `p` is handled as it is in `next()`, the `t` array is semantically rotated so that the current element is always the first one (`t[j] ^= s[(j + p) & 15];`). Then, right before the function terminates, `memcpy(s, t, sizeof t);` copies the new values from `t` back to `s` without considering the rotation at all. Just replace the `memcpy` with a proper loop including the `p` offset, then it should be fine.

(Well, but that doesn't mean `jump()` is really the same as *2^512* `next()`. But at least it *could* be.)

Comment: I decided to set `p = 0` after the `memcpy` instead, since as you mentioned, it's just a circular buffer.  I'll hold off on accepting for now since you answered the implicit question, but not the explicit question.

Comment: @bcrist You mean, how you can verify if `jump()` is really equivalent to 2^512 `next()` ?

Comment: Ideally, the algorithm to generate the magic bit vector `JUMP` for arbitrary *n*.

Comment: @bcrist What's exactly not clear with chapter 8 of the paper (assuming that the previous 7 chapters were read too)?

Answer (score 0):

As Vigna himself said, that was actually a bug.

While working on a Java implementation, I found, if not mistaken, a small improvement on the correct implementation:

If you update t array also circularly from p to p-1, then you can just memcpy it back to the state and it will work correctly.

Moreover, the loop updating t gets tighter, as you do not need to add p + j every time. For instance:

```
    int j = p;
    do {
        t[j] ^= s[j];
        ++j;
        j &= 15;
    } while (j != p);
```

Ok, as bcrist correctly noted, the previous code is wrong, as p changes for each bit in JUMP array. The best alternative I come up with is the following:

```
void jump() {
    static const uint64_t JUMP[] = { 0x84242f96eca9c41dULL,
        0xa3c65b8776f96855ULL, 0x5b34a39f070b5837ULL, 0x4489affce4f31a1eULL,
        0x2ffeeb0a48316f40ULL, 0xdc2d9891fe68c022ULL, 0x3659132bb12fea70ULL,
        0xaac17d8efa43cab8ULL, 0xc4cb815590989b13ULL, 0x5ee975283d71c93bULL,
        0x691548c86c1bd540ULL, 0x7910c41d10a1e6a5ULL, 0x0b5fc64563b3e2a8ULL,
        0x047f7684e9fc949dULL, 0xb99181f2d8f685caULL, 0x284600e3f30e38c3ULL
    };

    uint64_t t[16] = { 0 };
    const int base = p;
    int j = base;
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof JUMP / sizeof *JUMP; i++)
        for(int b = 0; b < 64; b++) {
            if (JUMP[i] & 1ULL << b) {
                int k = p;
                do {
                    t[j++] ^= s[k++];
                    j &= 15;
                    k &= 15;
                } while (j != base);
            }
            next();
        }

    memcpy(s, t, sizeof t);
}
```

As p will have its original value in the end, this should work.

Not very sure whether it is actually an improvement in performance, as I am trading one addition for an increment and a bitwise AND.
I think it will not be slower, even if increment is as expensive as addition, due to the lack of data dependency between j and k updates. Hopefully, it may be slightly faster.

Opinions / corrections are more than welcome.

Comment: Have you tested this?  Unless I misunderstand what you're suggesting, I don't think it will work.  `next()` increments/wraps `p` so in order for this to work properly you'd need to rotate the elements of `t` every time as well.

Comment: You are so right, @bcrist! Shame on me... I edit my answer with another (hopefully correct) proposal, though this time not clearly faster...